# How do you use LINQ to find the duplicate of a specific property?

Tags: c#, linq

```
Customer customerOne = new Customer("John", "Doe");
Customer customerTwo = new Customer("Super", "Man");
Customer customerThree = new Customer("Crazy", "Guy");
Customer customerFour = new Customer("Jane", "Doe");
Customer customerFive = new Customer("Bat", "Man");

List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
customers.Add(customerOne);
customers.Add(customerTwo);
customers.Add(customerThree);
customers.Add(customerFour);
customers.Add(customerFive);
```

What LINQ query would return an enumerable for all customers with the same last name?

Results should include one instance of: John Doe, Jane Doe, Super Man, and Bat Man

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
    var result = from c in customers
                 join c2 in customers on c.LastName equals c2.LastName
                 where c != c2
                 select c;
```

Comment: this is syntactically slightly more elegant than the "group by" solution, but also (much) less performant (although obviously the difference is only noticeable with very large lists)

Comment: Agreed. Is it O(n sqrt(n)) vs O(n^2)?

Comment: It would be interesting to see whether this is actually more performant when querying with SQL; a self-join is probably more natural for a query optimizer to handle, though I'm not sure what kind of SQL the provider would produce for the Group By solution.

Comment: @Dan Bryant probably, but that entirely depends on the linq provider and probably also the actual database engine. The question does not mention any db technology, so I'm assuming it's about linq 2 objects...

Answer (score 61):

Reformulated: "you want to group the list of customers by last name, filter out the groups with more than one element, and then select each instance of each group". You can almost literally translate this sentence to C#:

```
 customers
    .GroupBy(customer => customer.LastName)
    .Where(sameLastName => sameLastName.Skip(1).Any())
    .SelectMany(customer => customer)
```

or with LINQ syntax:

```
var q = from customer in customers
        group customer by customer.LastName into sameLastName
        where sameLastName.Skip(1).Any()
        from customer in sameLastName
        select customer;
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  Works for me, other did not.

Answer (score 8):

```
var groups = customers.GroupBy(c => c.LastName).Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any());
foreach(var group in groups) {
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
    foreach(var customer in group) {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + customer.FirstName);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Doe
        John
        Jane
Man
        Super
        Bat
```

You can flatten the resulting sequence of groups into one sequence with

```
var list = groups.SelectMany(g => g);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to find if there is a duplicate you can use this trick.

```
var result = customers.GroupBy(c => c.Id).Count() != customers.Count();
```

Comment: "If you just want to find if there is a duplicate". Yeah, but they don't.