# LINQ to Entity Query - duplicates in a group

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following table that holds a list of shifts and the user assigned to each of those shifts as below:

```
ShiftID | StartDateTime | EndDateTime | AssignedUserID |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I am trying to do is pull out the shiftID for all shifts that have been assigned to a user on the same date and time. This should not happen as a person cannot be in two places at once...(this one has been sorted...now)

We have some instances in our database where the same user has been assigned to work on 2 different shifts on the same date and time.

e.g.

```
56 | 06/08/2015 13:00:00 | 06/08/2015 17:00:00 | 22

64 | 06/08/2015 13:00:00 | 06/08/2015 17:00:00 | 22
```

Hope someone can help with this, even as a start to pull out the users who have been assigned to shifts on the same start date ?

```
public IList<ShiftDate> GetDuplicateShifts()
{
    return _UoW.ShiftDate.Get()
        .ToList();
}
```

UPDATE

OK, I'm getting there, I am now able to pull out all groups of users where the user is on 2 dates on the same day, the code below works:

```
public IList<ShiftDate> GetDuplicateShiftsByOrg(int orgID)
{
    IList<ShiftDate> AllDates = _UoW.ShiftDates
        .Get(s => s.Shift.organisationID == orgID)
        .Where(s=>s.assignedUserID != null)
        .ToList();

    var DuplicateDates = new List<ShiftDate> { };

    var groups = AllDates.GroupBy(s=>s.assignedUserID.Value).Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any());

    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        var group2 = group.GroupBy(sd => sd.shiftStartDate.Date).Where(a => a.Count() > 1).ToList();

        if (group2.Count() > 1)
        {


        ///// REF 1 : this pulls out all shiftdates in group one, I want all shiftdates in group2.

            foreach (ShiftDate shiftDate in group)
            {
                    DuplicateDates.Add(shiftDate);
            }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        }
    }

    return DuplicateDates.ToList();
}
```

As you will see at REF one above in the code I want to pull out the shiftdates in group2. However when I try to do this I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Grouping[System.DateTime,MySolution.POCO.ShiftDate]' to type 'MySolution.POCO.ShiftDate'.

UPDATE

The error above was appearing because I was trying to return a shiftdate from a group of shift dates, I had to add an extra loop to cycle through the groups first. See solution below

Comment: Questions on SO are supposed to have code. Please do some research and retry the question with some sample code and specific questions. :) To get you started, you might want to search things like "linq find matching datetime" To answer the question, we have no info on the schema and no idea what's not working for you right now...

Comment: added just a small bit of code...i know its hardly worth while, my attempts have been totally unfruitful!

Comment: You first need to use `GroupBy` on `AssignedUserID`. You now have one group for every user assigned to at least one shift: the key is the ID and the value is the list of records. Next you need to check for duplicates inside the `value.Shifts` list using [list duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4250270/2474175).

Comment: @AndreiV Thanks, this helped a lot, im nearly there, updated my question with my solution

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var dt=DateTime.Now().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
var result = from t in Table1
WHERE c.StartDate=dt
SELECT new {c.AssignedUserID};
```

Comment: this isnt helpful at all

Comment: well, that was all I could produce before the update, not given enough details

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working by using multiple groups, see working code below:

```
 public IList<ShiftDate> GetDuplicateShiftsByOrg(int orgID)
    {
        IList<ShiftDate> AllDates = _UoW.ShiftDates
            .Get(s => s.Shift.organisationID == orgID)
            .Where(s=>s.assignedUserID != null)
            .ToList();

        var DuplicateDates = new List<ShiftDate> { };

        /// 1. Group all shifts assigned to user
        var groupUserShifts = AllDates.GroupBy(s=>s.assignedLocumID.Value).Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any());

        foreach (var group in groupUserShifts)
        {
            /// 2. Group all shifts assigned to user on the same date
            var groupUserSameDates = group.GroupBy(sd => sd.shiftStartDate.Date).Where(a => a.Count() > 1).ToList();


            if (groupUserSameDates.Count() > 1)
            {
                foreach (var dategroup in groupUserSameDates)
                {
                    /// 3. Return all shifts where user hass been assigned on the same date
                    foreach (ShiftDate shiftDate in dategroup)
                    {
                        DuplicateDates.Add(shiftDate);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return DuplicateDates.ToList();
    }
```